How do I find the exact row of a table using Playwright & C# when there is similar text

Using Playwright written with C#
I have a table with various columns and rows.
Each row has a unique name and on the same row there are some
buttons.
I am only interested in the delete/remove button from the button set.

Using this playwright code:
        public static async Task ClickScenarioDeleteButton(IPage Page, string scenarioName)
        {
            //var deleteButton = Page.Locator($"div:has-text('{scenarioName}') >> data-testid=generic-remove-button")
            //    .First;
            //await deleteButton.ClickAsync();

                await Page
                    .GetByRole(AriaRole.Row)
                    .Filter(new() { HasText = scenarioName })
                    .GetByTestId("generic-remove-button")
                    .ClickAsync();
            
        }

works if there is only one value of "PWATest_20240430_100831".
However, if you add another row with the prefix of "No2Sch" + "PWATest_20240430_100831" then when running the code, I am getting an error:
Message: 
  Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException : Error: strict mode violation: GetByRole(AriaRole.Row).Filter(new() { HasText = "PWATest_20240430_100831" }).GetByTestId("generic-remove-button") resolved to 2 elements:
      1) <button type="button" data-testid="generic-remove-button…>…</button> aka GetByRole(AriaRole.Row, new() { Name = "CustomerName PWATest_20240430_100831 24 Hours None" }).GetByTestId("generic-remove-button")
      2) <button type="button" data-testid="generic-remove-button…>…</button> aka GetByRole(AriaRole.Row, new() { Name = "CustomerName No2SchPWATest_20240430_100831 24 Hours None" }).GetByTestId("generic-remove-button")

 "CustomerName" will be the same.
I have tried all sorts of approaches and still cannot fathom how I can specify exact text.
You can't use it in the .filter, unless you are using something other than C# as it doesn't recognise Exact = true.
Has anyone else had a similar issue and if so, how did you get your code to work please?
 If it helps, here is the html for the row:
<td data-label="Valid" class="mud-table-cell"><div class="scenario-validity" b-ho1i1ctrb5=""><!--!--><div class="icon-component" b-ehxpcnsxe0=""><!--!--><div class="mud-tooltip-root mud-tooltip-inline"><!--!--><svg class="mud-icon-root mud-svg-icon mud-success-text mud-icon-size-small" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><!--!--><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm-2 15-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path></svg><!--!--><div id="popover-1f0d4cb7-5b9a-4b7a-80c5-54be38c1bcf0" class="mud-popover-cascading-value"></div></div></div></div></td>


Those buttons are not in the HTML you shared. Do you have two buttons in that row?

Yes. The buttons belong to the same row.

The actual HTML matters a lot. And right now it's not readable. We can't guess what row or column you want to retrieve from incomplete text. There may be better locator combinations, based on the tags or styles. You can use CSS locators based on the column index too.

The first and foremost thing you could try is change "HasText" to "HasTextRegex". More examples are described here.
